# How to query the document based on Date field in MongoDB?

Tags: java, mongodb

In MongoDB, I have the date field value as specified here:

```
ISODate(2015-01-12T05:00:00.000+0000)
```

How can I retrieve the document based on this date field using Java. I'm sending this string `2015-01-12T05:00:00.000+0000` as a parameter to a method. I'm trying to convert this string to Date and trying to retrieve the document from MongoDB.

I'm unable to fix this issue. I am using Java 7.

Comment: have you checked mongo db api?

Comment: HI dev777 - can you show us what you've tried so far, and explain in what way or ways it hasn't worked? Has it errored, or failed to find the data you were looking for, or something else?

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that you have a correct java Date object, and then query like this:

```
 Date myDate = <whatever>;

 MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient();
 MongoCollection<Document> coll = mongoClient.getDatabase("test").getCollection("xyz");

 FindIterable<Document> result = coll.find(Filters.eq("myDateField", myDate));
```

Note, that this is java driver 3.x standard.

Comment: How to convert String "2015-01-12T05:00:00.000+0000" to jave Date Object ?

Comment: Date date = Date.from(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ").parse("2015-01-12T05:00:00.000+0000", ZonedDateTime::from).toInstant())   - note however, that there currently seems to be no supported way to use actual time zones apart from the default JVM timezone, as the mongo driver only supports the simple date, which basically drops timezone information. We can only hope for a better future version right now.

Comment: Which maven dependency, do we nned to use for DateFormatter ?

Comment: This is basic Java 8

Comment: Actually I'm using java7. How can we modify the above code ?

Comment: First of all, java 8 has been the standard for more than two years now - time to upgrade. Then, we have left the ground of the original question, which - at least in my understanding - was centered around searching for dates in mongo, and *not* around parsing date formats in java. You will find plenty of information about this using a simple search.